# add row in jqgrid using grails

Tags: jquery, grails, jqgrid

i am new for grails.

i am using jqgrid version "jqgrid4.4.3". i am loading grid and editing. all work s fine. My need is to add row not by using submitform or other forms.

i need to use a button named as "ADD". when i click the add button, i need to add a new empty row.For example,$("#grid").jqGrid('addRow', "new"); . In which i need to type the value. then, i need to click the another button named as "SAVE" to pass the value from gsp to controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go to [jqGrid Demo page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and in left navigation  you will see **Row Editing (new)** and inside it there is **Inline Navigator (new)**. This is inline version  of adding row. However if you want pop-up form while adding row then see **New in version 3.7 >> Add/edit/delete on local data**. I have implemented inline row adding from this example only.

I hope this is the one you are looking for.

Comment: thanks Aman Adhikari. It is good link..but i new in grails. i tried that coding , the navgrid and inlineGrid  not dispaly  in my gsp to click '+' option to add a new row to acheive my need. any help ?